# Time Complexity Theory not matching up with practical experiment for Linear Search

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm working with the Linear Search Algorithm and from the theory of this algorithm its time complexity is O(n). Now I have to prove this using actual code and create a graph proving the algorithm is in fact O(n). But some the practical results doesn't show this at all.

Here is my coding methodology used:

1. I have a loop that creates an array dynamically based on the loop number.
2. I then fill this array randomly with numbers.
3. I then implement the Linear Search Algorithm. Now before the Algorithm runs I take note of the time and once value I am searching for is found I stop the clock and save the times and at the end of the loop I write the values to a text file.
4. I then Import the text'file into excel and create a graph. But the results doesn't corroborate the fact that the algorithm is O(n)

Here is my code in java:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        long[] ArrayTimeTaken = new long[10000];
        String Display = "";
        
        //Code that runs the linear search
        for (int i = 2; i < 10000; i++) 
        {
            int[] arrayExperimentTest = new int[i];
            arrayExperimentTest = FillArray(i);
            int ValuetoSearchfor = Math.round(((arrayExperimentTest.length)/2));
            System.out.println(ValuetoSearchfor);
            ArrayTimeTaken[i] = LinearSearch(arrayExperimentTest,ValuetoSearchfor);
            Display = Display+ System.getProperty("line.separator") + ArrayTimeTaken[i]; 
           
        }
        PrintWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/Roberto/Desktop/testing.txt", "UTF-8");
            writer.println(Display);
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //ChartCreate(ArrayTimeTaken);  
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

Here is the code for the filling of the array with random numbers and the Linear Search:

```
 //This code simply populates our array with numbers in each of the array positions
    static int[] FillArray(int number)
    {
        int[] ArrayofValues = new int[number];
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) 
        {
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            boolean flag = true;
            while (flag) 
            {                
                int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(number);
                if (ArrayofValues[index] == 0)
                {
                    ArrayofValues[index] = i;
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return ArrayofValues;
    }
    
    //This function does a linear search on an array with integers
    static long LinearSearch(int[] ArraySearch,int ValueFind)
    {
        long TimeTaken = 0;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.gc();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < ArraySearch.length; i++) 
        {
            if (ArraySearch[i] == ValueFind) 
            {
                TimeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                break;
            }
            
        }
        return TimeTaken;
        
    }
```

Here is a graph of the results. Shouldn't I be getting a straight line graph?
[image]

Comment: Benchmarking like this is hard, the runtime/compiler might optimize away.

Comment: "results doesn't corroborate the fact that the algorithm is O(n)".Could you please elaborate??

Comment: Why are you explicitly kicking off a garbage-collection run *after* you take your starting timestamp?

Comment: I have added the a graph above adding more clarity to the problem. Also I take it I'm meant to implement the garbage collection before I start timing?

Comment: Just a thought I had by looking at the graph. Don't you think the array is way too small? You may not notice differences when they are all in milliseconds. Use larger arrays and run the test several times so that operations would take at least several seconds and would be less affected by "noise" on your machine.

Comment: O(n) doesn't mean every search is O(n). If you search the first item its 1, if you search the last or an item which isn't in the array it's n. You have will never have a "straight line graph".

Comment: Okay firstly the Garbage collection line above was in the wrong place and needs to go above the long TimeTaken = 0; line. It was the garbage collection line that was giving me the times shown above in the graph. I'm currently running the array for a size of a million. Will report back after the program finishes! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your testing methodology, but mostly:

- the resolution of `System.currentMillis()` is not great, so considering your results are all blow 12ms, I would not trust them
- you run a full GC **during** your measurement, which makes no sense: the GC itself is probably going to take a few milliseconds

So:

- make your arrays significantly larger - you could run a test with sizes from 10,000 to 10,000,000 in increment of 10,000 for example
- move the GC to *before* `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you were right I was doing the garbage collection after I started timing hence the result I got in the graph above. I move the gc before the timing and ran the loop for really large array numbers (10 million + ) and got useful results! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You cannot infer results from a single run.  Use something like [Google Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) to do microbenchmarking properly, this will generate all sorts of useful metrics for you (standard deviation etc), and many important technical things (warm up the JVM so bytecode is likely to be optimized).

In addition to assylias's answer - doing IO may have a huge impact on your results.  It is also good practice to run on OS without graphical UI and with minimal number of services running.

Read the [Caliper wiki](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/w/list) for best practice microbenchmarking and look at the [source for examples](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/source/browse/#git/examples/src/main/java/examples).

(**Edit**: for version 1.0-beta-1 check this [branch for examples](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/source/browse/?name=caliper-1.0-beta-1#git/examples/src/main/java/examples), the API is changing and master doesn't match the documentation)